# Where is compass 1.0.0 preview Documentation located?

Tags: css, compass-sass

I can't find the documentation anyway. So The follow error

```
     error sass/style.scss (Line 7 of _home.scss: Undefined mixin 'clearfix'.)
```

Is fine, but I need the clearfix with compass.

Comment: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/general/clearfix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also was looking to documentation but on project site it's old version only and no info about 1.0 version or even 0.12.6 . I think it's better to use old stable version (I also installed 1.0 version but had some problems and I'm back to 0.12.6)

I've just found https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/doc-src/content/CHANGELOG.markdown so it seams documentation is on http://beta.compass-style.org/

Comment: Nice one marcin :D fantastic. How did you even find it?

Comment: Look at this link on gitbub in answer :) I was simply browsing github folders to find any info about documentation